# Is Comscore.framwork file is available for armv7s architecture?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, armv7

For analytics we are trying to integrate Comscore.framework to our project. It gets build failed if I use armv7s Architecture. The issue got resolved when building it with armv6 but my question is, Do Comscore.framwork file available for armv7s architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a commandline tool to see what archs are included into binary.

```
cd /Users/.../Downloads/comscore-master/comScore.framework/Versions/Current
$ ls
Headers         Resources       comScore
$ file comScore 
comScore: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
comScore (for architecture armv7):      current ar archive random library
comScore (for architecture armv7s):     current ar archive random library
comScore (for architecture i386):       current ar archive random library
```

I think that you can build any number or archs you want and then merge them using lipo tool into one static library and bundle it like framework.